# Queue implementation bug C++

Tags: c++, queue

I am facing a very specific problem when trying to implement a generic queue in C++. Here is the code:

```
template <class T> class Queue  {

    private:
        T * queue;
        int front;
        int back;
        int MAX_SIZE;

    public:
        Queue(){
            Queue(SOME_PREDEFINED_CONSTANT);
        }

        Queue(int size){
            queue = new T[size];
            MAX_SIZE = size;
            front = 0;
            back = 0;
            cout << "inside constructor:" << " back= " << back <<  " front=" << front << endl;

        }

        void push(const T entry){

            if(back < MAX_SIZE){
                queue[back] = entry;
                back++;
            }
        }

        T peek(){

            return queue[front]; 
        }

        void pop(){

            if(size() > 0){
                front++;
            }
            if(front==back){
                front = 0;
                back = 0;
            }
        }

        int size(){
            cout << "size:" << " back=" << back <<  " front=" << front << endl;
            return (back-front);
        }
};
```

When I am initializing the queue, like this: `Queue <int> q;`, I get the correct values of `back` and `front` inside the constructor; The output:

> inside constructor: back=0 front=0

But when I am asking for the size of the queue, like this: `q.size()` (without any push/pop operation), I get very weird values of `back` and `front`. One sample output:

> size: back=32766 front=-746749592

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This: `Queue(){   Queue(SOME_PREDEFINED_CONSTANT);` is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: `Queue() : Queue(SOME_PREDEFINED_CONSTANT) {}` As written, your default constructor does not initialize any members. In its body, it creates and immediately discards a temporary `Queue`, which has zero effect.

Comment: Read about the [rule of 0/3/5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: In addition to @Igor: `Queue(int size = SOME_PREDEFINED_CONSTANT)` achieves the same as "two in one". If `Queue` is constructed without argument, `SOME_PREDEFINED_CONSTANT` is used as default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
Queue(){
    Queue(SOME_PREDEFINED_CONSTANT);
}
```

What happens is that you inside the default constructor create a *temporary* object which immediately go out of scope and is destructed.

There are two ways of solving this:

1. The "new" way using a constructor initializer list and delegating constructors:

   ```
   Queue() : Queue(SOME_PREDEFINED_CONSTANT)
   { /* empty */ }
   ```
2. The "old" way using default arguments:

   ```
   template <class T> class Queue  {
       ...

   public:
       Queue(int size = SOME_PREDEFINED_CONSTANT){
           ...
       }
       ...
   };
   ```

Comment: delegating constructors is C++14?

Comment: @user463035818 C++11